# Unable to loop through titles on a search results page then print them to console in Python/Selenium

Tags: python, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

Good day,

I'm learning Selenium in Python (django back end) and what I'd like to be able to do is print all of the sauce names on the search results page to the console using a for loop. I cannot seem to get it to print anything to the console. The element I wish to loop through is CLASS-NAME = "sauce-name" which is nested inside a multiple cards with CLASS-NAME = "card".

Website I'm testing on (my own site): https://www.ionme.dev.

The steps taken by webdriver are (these work up to step 5 which is to iterate and print:

1. Open site in Chrome
2. Click on hamburger in top right hand corner
3. Search for ghost
4. Search results I wish to iterate through are displayed
5. Loop through sauce titles and print to console

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

service = Service()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

driver.get("http://ionme.dev")

dropdown = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "navbar-toggler-icon")
dropdown.click()

search = driver.find_element("name", "secret_sauce_search_query")
search.send_keys("ghost")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "title"))
    )

    titles = main.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "card")
    for title in titles:
        header = title.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sauce-name")
        print(header.text)

except:
    driver.close()
```

Source Code:

```
<div class="search-card-section">
        <br>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="row no-gutters">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <a href="/sauces/25/melindas-ghost-pepper-sauce" class="nav-link sauce-name">Ghost Pepper Sauce</a>
                            <a href="/manufacturers/17/melindas" class="nav-link manufacturer-name">Melinda's</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            
                            Bhut Jolokia
                            <br>
                            
                            Ghost
                            <br>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="row no-gutters">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <a href="/sauces/26/melindas-ghost-pepper-steak-sauce" class="nav-link sauce-name">Ghost Pepper Steak Sauce</a>
                            <a href="/manufacturers/17/melindas" class="nav-link manufacturer-name">Melinda's</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            
                            Ghost
                            <br>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your case depends on resolution, as far as `.navbar-toggler-icon` is present only for mobile view.

Then `#title` element doesn't have child element `.card`. They are placed on the same level as `#title`.

So you should search from root, not from `#title` element itself.
This code works for me:

```py
service = Service()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://ionme.dev")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
custom_width = 700
custom_height = 1200
driver.set_window_size(custom_width, custom_height)

dropdown = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.navbar-toggler")))
dropdown.click()

search = driver.find_element("name", "secret_sauce_search_query")
search.send_keys("ghost")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

titles = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "card")))
for title in titles:
    header = title.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sauce-name")
    print(header.text)
```

Output:

```
Ghost Pepper Sauce
Ghost Pepper Steak Sauce
Ghost Pepper Wing Sauce
fool's paradise
Qi
Tiki Torture
Ghost Pepper
The Last Dab
Retsuko Rage
Ancho Masala
Aka Miso
```